# Extract Delta from MV

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have declared MV logs on 4 source tables (database A ) and then I have created 4 Materialized Views on this tables (Database B using dblinks ) with FAST Refresh which works fine. But I need to use this Materialized view which would be refreshed every 5 minutes and I want to extract recent changes i.e Delta only and then apply to 4-5 different target tables. This are big tables and target tables needs to refreshed instantly how can I get just delta ?

May seem obvious to some but I am not able to design reliable process/mechanism. Any help/suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Add column to your MV with default sysdate, for example "date_delta". And then use this case:  WHERE date_delta >= sysdate - 5/1440 (5/1440 - it's 5 minutes)